# Why does my React button only work once and then stop?

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs

I am creating a simple Thermostat program with .NET - I am using React on the front end and C# on the back end. I want the app to be able My code looks like this:

ThermostatController.cs:

```
namespace ThermostatDotNet.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ThermostatController : Controller
    {

        private int _Temperature { get; set; }

        public ThermostatController()
        {
            _Temperature = 20;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("GetTemp")]
        public int GetTemp()
        {
            return _Temperature;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Reset")]
        public int Reset()
        {
            _Temperature = 20;
            return _Temperature;
        }

        [HttpGet, Route("Increase")]
        public int Increase()
        {
            _Temperature += 1;
            return _Temperature;
        }
    }
}
```

Thermostat.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export class Thermostat extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { temp: "" };


    fetch("api/Thermostat/GetTemp/")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ temp: data });
      });
    }

    increaseTemp() {
       fetch("api/Thermostat/Increase/")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ temp: data });
      });
    }

     reset() {
       fetch("api/Thermostat/Reset/")
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ temp: data });
      });
    }


  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Thermostat</h1>
            <p>The temperature is: {this.state.temp}°C</p>

         <button onClick={() => this.increaseTemp()}>Increase</button>
         <button onClick={() => this.reset()}>Reset</button>
       </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is that every time I click the "Increase" button, the temperature increases by 1, but then stops. I keep pressing but nothing increases any further. Can anyone please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because inside `increaseTemp` looks like you are simply fetching the temperature value and setting it to the state, change the `setState` to the second form where it accepts a callback and update value based on the previous state.

Comment: Thank you @RajeshKumar - what do you mean by the second form? (sorry, I am really new to React)

Comment: Please visit this [link](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and check this example 


`this.setState((state) => {
  return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
});`